# How to count the number of occurrence of consecutive numbers using Excel or other software?

Tags: excel, count, primes

I am a Ph.D. student. I am now working with my paper on prime numbers but I have a difficulty in programming. I hope someone out there can help me solve this problem. Here's the scenario:

Suppose that I have a list of prime gaps:

```
1
2
2
4
2
4
2
4
6
2
6
4
2
4
6
```

I want to know the number of instances that a number 2 is being followed by 4. In the case above, the number of instances that 2 is followed by 4 is four times. I want also to know how many times that the number 4 is followed by 6 and etc.

In the data above there are only 15 but it's difficult to count if you have a bulk of data. At the moment I have already 283,146 data and it's very hard for me to do it if I have no program.

Answer (score 2):

With your list in column A and your choices of first and second values in B1 and C1 respectively:

`=COUNTIFS(A1:A1048575,B1,A2:A1048576,C1)`

Note that, with almost all other array-processing functions, referencing ranges of such sizes would not at all be a good idea. However, COUNTIF(S)/SUMIF(S) employ implicit detection of the used-range from any range passed and so operate over those cells only, so there is little or no loss in performance when referencing arbitrarily large ranges.

Regards

Comment: Nice use of offset ranges.

Answer (score 1):

@XOR LX answer is perfect and, as @Jeeped says, it makes an optimal use of offset ranges. However, you have to manually define the list of values in columns B:C, and if you have to repeat the analysis multiple times and the range of unique primes that satisfy the condition is never the same, it can be a little tedious. If you want to achieve an automatic result in less than 30 secs. for 1 million rows, you can try the following VBA code.

The only assumption is that the data is in column A. If this is not the case, the best option is to copy the column with your data to column A in a new Sheet. With this data structure, you should not have problems.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub countPrimes()

Dim LRC As Long, LRPrimes As Long, count As Integer, lRowB As Long, Rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


LRC = 0

Range("A1").Activate

While Not ActiveCell = ""
    If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value - 2 Then
    LRC = LRC + 1
    Range("B" & LRC).Value = ActiveCell.Value
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Wend

Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Range("C1")
Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown)).Sort key1:=Range("C1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

lRowB = Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = Range("B1:B" & lRowB)

Range("C1").Activate


While Not ActiveCell = ""
    count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, ActiveCell.Value)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = count
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Wend

Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

### How it works?

It iterates through Column A and compares each cell in the column (x) with the cell below it (y). `If x = y -2`, then it copies the value of x to the first empty row in column B. After iterating through the entire column, it generates a list of unique primes in column C, ASC ordered. In this new column, there is another iteration, but this time, it counts the times each value in column C appears in column B and puts the value in column D. Column B is deleted, as it is not useful anymore. The result:

- Column A: your original data
- Column B: a list of unique primes
- Column C: the count

### How to implement in Excel?

In case you have never worked with macros, [this official website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-macro-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b#bmcreatemacrovba) can help you doing it.